# Photos smart album for photos with no people at all

Tags: macos, photos.app

The macOS Photos app allows searching for photos that contain specific people. But how can one create a smart album that only contains photos that do *not* contain any people at all?

It is possible to create a filter that excludes a specific person.  That filter might be a solution if there only was a way to exclude *all* persons using a wildcard or similar.

Answer (score 6):

---

**Update: This no longer works and I no longer have a Mac to test**

---

The smart albums use SQL at the core so you may use % as a wildcard.

```
Person is not %
```

If you create a smart album with the above, it will populate full of photos where the facial recognition did not match a photo.  However, people with a detected face that has not yet been named will also show up in the album.

Comment: This does not work on Catalina 10.15.7.

Comment: Doesn't work on Big Sur.  Cannot type in percent symbol

Comment: Tried on macOS 11.5.2 / Photos 6.0 (361.0.100). Doesn't seem to work anymore.

Comment: This no longer works, but I was able to get close by adding in 5 rules: Person does not include a, person does not include e, and repeat for all vowels. Not perfect, but my guess is that 99.9% of people will have at least one vowel in their name.

Comment: @TimDoyle This also matches everything without people ...

Answer (score 1):

managed to do it by selecting blank in the listbox when choosing a face:

[image]